# Как правильно асинхронно отправить запрос и обработать ответ?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Отправляю Post запрос, а затем его обрабатываю - десериализую и пересылаю ответ:

```
// Отправка запроса на API др. сервиса
                string jsonRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestMessage);
                string jsonResponseData = await PostRequestHttpAsync(url, jsonRequest);

                ResponseMessageData responseData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseMessageData>(jsonResponseData);

                await _telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, responseData.TextMessage, ParseMode.Default, replyMarkup: new ForceReplyMarkup { Selective = true });
```

Дождется ли при таком варианте операция `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseMessageData>(jsonResponseData);` исполнения кода запроса `PostRequestHttpAsync(url, jsonRequest);`?

Дождется ли `_telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync` того же кода?

Из оф. доков понял, что директива  await говорит о том, что отсюда мы передаем управление в точку вызвавший данный метод и продолжаем выполнять код, который идет после вызова данной асинхронной функции не дожидаясь её исполнения, в моем случае нужно дождаться.
Объясните пожалуйста как правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` завершает метод, который преобразуется компилятором в асинхронную машину состояний, и возврат к выполнению происходит в ту же точку, из которой был выход после того как асинхронная операция будет выполнена (или завершится с ошибкой).

Код текущего метода не продолжает выполняться, пока `await` не дождется завершения вызванной асинхронной операции.

В показанном коде проблем не наблюдаю, всё должно работать как ожидается.

Логически `await`, примененный сразу к вызову асинхронного метода работает как в синхронном коде.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Запускаю операцию");
var result = await MethodAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Операция завершена");
```

А вот то что нельзя сделать в синхронном коде, так это вот так.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Запускаю операцию");
var task = MethodAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Операция выполняется");
var result = await task;
Console.WriteLine("Операция завершена");
```

То есть при желании можно продолжить выполнение кода и в текущем методе, а дождаться завершения операции позднее.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!